# Code: 2500 message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." type: "OAuthException" (FB Photo Share)

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-4

I have a Facebook user logged in through a PHP controller in Laravel 4 (using the Taylor Otwell package), but I am unsure of how to get my access token to my javascript SDK call to share a photo (/me/photos).

Here is the Javascript, which is called on a click:

```
/* make the API call */
function facebookInit() {
   FB.api(
      "/me/photos",
      "POST",
      {
         "object": {
            "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/**********/picture?width=720&height=720"
         }
      },
      function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          if (response && !response.error) {
              window.location = "http://url.com/artists";
          }
      }
    );
}
```

When logging the response, I get the error:

> Code: 2500 message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." type: "OAuthException" (FB Photo Share)

I have a user logged in with access token, but I am not sure how to get that read by this javascript SDK call.  Here is the code in the controller logging in a user:

```
public function action_session($provider, $id = null) {
        //get facebook sdk
        $this->facebook = $this->getFacebook($provider);

        //get facebook auth
        $this->auth = $this->getFacebookAuth();
        if($this->auth) {
            return $this->auth;
        }

        //get facebook access token
        $this->accessToken = $this->getAccessToken();

        //set facebook access token
        $this->facebook->accessToken = $this->accessToken;

        if(!session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }

        $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = $this->accessToken;

        //get data
        $data = array();

        //get user
        $data['user'] = $this->getUser();

        //check if exists (redirect)
        $fan = new Fan();
        $check = $fan->getFan($data['user']['id']);

        if(isset($check->url_tag) && !empty($check->url_tag)) {
            $login = Fan::where('fbid', '=', $data['user']['id'])->first();
            Auth::login($login);
            return Redirect::to('/fans/'.$check->url_tag);
            exit;
        }        

        //get picture
        $data['picture'] = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$data['user']['id'].'/picture?width=720&height=720';

        //get friends
        $data['friends'] = $this->getFriends();

        //get likes
        $data['likes'] = $this->getLikes();

        //get location
        $data['location'] = $this->getLocation();

        //assign global data
        $this->data = $data;

        //check if user exists
        if(!$this->userExists($this->data['user']['id'])) {
            $this->createFan();
        };

        //login user
        $login = Fan::where('fbid', '=', $data['user']['id'])->first();
        Auth::login($login);



    return $this->forceRedirect('/fans/welcome');

    }

    public function getFacebook($provider) {        
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'crowd.com') {
            return OAuth2::provider($provider, array('id' => '*************', 'secret' => '*************'));
        } else {
            return OAuth2::provider($provider, array('id' => '*************', 'secret' => '**************'));
        }        
    }

    public function getFacebookAuth() {
        if(!isset($_GET['code'])) {     
            return $this->facebook->authorize();
        }
    }

    public function getAccessToken() {
        return $this->facebook->access($_GET['code']);
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->facebook->get('me');
    }
```

My question is how do I take the access token for the logged in user from my controller and have it connected to the Javascript SDK so I can run this call?

I know it is registering a user as logged in to Facebook because I can use FB.ui events just fine (it will recognize the logged in FB user).

Comment: Why aren't you using the PHP SDK to do this?

Comment: It just seemed simpler to do it this way, because I already had a javascript flow with an on click event.